# slide show using javascript using php variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to get member photos from my sql and show as a slide. i am trying this with  DHTML slideshow script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com) check the basic code here [basic code](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/dhtmlslide_dev.htm)

now i change the code to get the image url from mysql using php

my code :

```
Here is the html and script code.
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* DHTML slideshow script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice must stay intact for legal use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/
var photos = new Array()
<?php
 $mid=$_POST['mid'];
//echo $mid;
$mid=$_POST['mid'];
require_once("datacon.php"); 
    $result = $data->query("SELECT * FROM tempregist where id= $mid ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error());
$folde= "uploads/thumb/";   
$folder=utf8_encode($folde);

//echo $folder;
     $mid1 =$row['mid'];
    require_once("datacon.php"); 
    $result = $data->query("SELECT image_name FROM tbl_images where mid= '$mid1' ");

$phparray = array();
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>=1)
{

    while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $i=0;
    $phparray[$i] = $folder. $crow['image_name'];

    $i++;
?>


photos<?php  echo"[".$i."]" ;?>  =  <?php echo '"'.  implode( $phparray) . '"'."\n" ; 
} }



  ?>

var photoslink = new array
var x
x =<?php echo json_encode($count) ?>;
var which=0

/
//Specify whether images should be linked or not (1=linked)
var linkornot=0

Set corresponding URLs for above images. Define ONLY if variable linkornot equals "1"
photoslink[0]=""
photoslink[1]=""
photoslink[2]=""

//do NOT edit pass this line

var preloadedimages=new Array()
for (i=0;i<photos.length;i++){
preloadedimages[i]=new Image()
preloadedimages[i].src=photos[i]
}


function applyeffect(){
if (document.all && photoslider.filters){
photoslider.filters.revealTrans.Transition=Math.floor(Math.random()*23)
photoslider.filters.revealTrans.stop()
photoslider.filters.revealTrans.apply()
}
}



function playeffect(){
if (document.all && photoslider.filters)
photoslider.filters.revealTrans.play()
}

function keeptrack(){
window.status="Image "+(which+1)+" of "+photos.length
}


function backward(){
if (which>0){
which--
applyeffect()
document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
playeffect()
keeptrack()
}
}

function forward(){
if (which<photos.length-1){
which++
applyeffect()
document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
playeffect()
keeptrack()
}
}

function transport(){
window.location=photoslink[which]
}

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" border = "2" align="center" alt="no logo">
</div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="2" height="22"><center>
<script>
if (linkornot==1)
document.write('<a href="javascript:transport()">')
document.write('<img src="'+photos[0]+'" name="photoslider" style="filter:revealTrans(duration=2,transition=23)" border=0>')
if (linkornot==1)
document.write('</a>')
</script>
</center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" height="21"><p align="left"><a href="#" onClick="backward();return false">Previous Slide</a></td>
    <td width="50%" height="21"><p align="right"><a href="#" onClick="forward();return false">Next Slide</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p align="center"><font face="Arial" size="-2">Free DHTML scripts provided by<br>
<a href="http://dynamicdrive.com">Dynamic Drive</a></font></p>





</body>
</html>
```

Now i am getting out put as follows
var photos = new Array()

```
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/220816_1412135472.jpeg"
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/312840_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/589453_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/467341_1412135630.jpeg"
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/800658_1412135790.jpeg"
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/366793_1412135826.jpeg"
```

But i need the out put like this

```
photos[0]  =  "uploads/thumb/220816_1412135472.jpeg"
photos[1]  =  "uploads/thumb/312840_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[2]  =  "uploads/thumb/589453_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[3]  =  "uploads/thumb/467341_1412135630.jpeg"
photos[4]  =  "uploads/thumb/800658_1412135790.jpeg"
photos[5]  =  "uploads/thumb/366793_1412135826.jpeg"
```

i tried so much. please any one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$i=0;
```

You're resetting $i in your loop

Comment: returns with same out put

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $data->query("SELECT image_name FROM tbl_images where mid= '$mid1' ");
{
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>=1)
{
    $i=0;
    while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $phparray[$i] = $folder. $crow['image_name'];
    echo $i. "\n";
    $i++;
}
}
```

use $i=0 initialization outside while

Comment: I t gives out put like this `code`var photos = new Array()
0
1
2
3
4
5


photos[6]  =  "uploads/thumb/220816_1412135472.jpeguploads/thumb/312840_1412135511.jpeguploads/thumb/589453_1412135511.jpeguploads/thumb/467341_1412135630.jpeguploads/thumb/800658_1412135790.jpeguploads/thumb/366793_1412135826.jpeg"

Comment: after end while loop just put , echo "<pre>";print_r($phparray); show the output

Answer (score 0):

finally i found it with help of Hammerstein and Dhanush Bala. i mingled two persons suggestion i got it here is the answer

```
$phparray = array();
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>=1)
{
    $b=0;
    while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
    $i=0;
    $phparray[$i] = $folder. $crow['image_name'];
       $i++;
    $b++;
?>


photos<?php  echo"[".$b."]" ;?>  =  <?php echo '"'.  implode( $phparray) . '"'."\n" ; 
} }
```

now the out put is:

```
photos[1]  =  "uploads/thumb/220816_1412135472.jpeg"
photos[2]  =  "uploads/thumb/312840_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[3]  =  "uploads/thumb/589453_1412135511.jpeg"
photos[4]  =  "uploads/thumb/467341_1412135630.jpeg"
photos[5]  =  "uploads/thumb/800658_1412135790.jpeg"
photos[6]  =  "uploads/thumb/366793_1412135826.jpeg"
```

thanks Hammerstein and Dhanush Bala